# Is the canonical map $\pi: F \to R$ of an algebra $R$ over a field $F$ injective if and only if $R$, as a ring, is not the zero ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, vector-spaces

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

I refer to [Section B.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlJ4M.png), [Section B.3 (part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7swB.png) and [Section B.3 (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztQCh.png) and to [Invariant Polynomials on $\mathfrak{gl} (r,F)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386728/).

---

**Question**: Is the proof of Proposition B.5 actually assuming $R$ is not the algebra with exactly 1 element unless there's some convention like "with identity" means "not the zero ring"?

- I think the statement Proposition B.5 need not assume $R$ is not the algebra with exactly 1 element, but a part of the proof does, namely that the canonical map $\pi: F \to R$ is injective if and only if $R$ is not the algebra with exactly 1 element. I believe the preceding sentence is equivalent to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Algebras_and_rings)'s "$A$ is the zero ring, or that $\eta$ is injective." I of course assume $R$, as a ring, is the zero ring if and only if $R$, as an algebra, is the algebra with exactly 1 element. I notice another textbook made the same error, so there might be a convention I'm not aware of.

---

Update: I notice it says "with identity 1" and not just "with identity" or something like "unital". Probably a convention.

Comment: If $F$ is a field and $R$ is non-zero left $F$-module, $a\in R-0$ then $f\mapsto fa$ is injective $F\to R$. Then $\{0\}$ is the zero Lie algebra, I don't think it can be called an algebra nor a ring. If $R$ is a ring and $a^2=a$ and $a$ commutes with $fa$ (in particular if $R$ is a $F$-algebra) then $f\mapsto fa$ is an injective ring homomorphism $F\to R$, and I think the word natural map and embedding $F\to R$ is reserved for when $R$ is unital and $a=1$.

Comment: Proposition B.5 would be immediately true for R=0, wouldn’t it? I’ve seen books ignore the R=0 case before

Comment: @coldnumber For "wouldn’t it?": No, I think you are right. I did say "I think the statement Proposition B.5 need not assume". For "I’ve seen books ignore the R=0 case": I did say "I notice another textbook made the same error, so there might be a convention I'm not aware of." Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that $f\mapsto f\cdot 1$ is injective is indeed wrong since $R$ could be the zero algebra.  Note though that the injectivity of this map is never used in the proof so the proof remains correct without it.

Comment: Thanks! Now to get to your answer on the other question.