# Invariant Polynomials on $\mathfrak{gl} (r,\mathbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, vector-spaces

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

I refer to [Section B.1 (part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlJ4M.png), [Section B.1 (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHYH6.png), [Section B.3 (part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7swB.png),[Section B.3 (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztQCh.png), [Section 23.1 (part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmbFe.png) and [Section 23.1 (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHP6h.png) and to [Invariant Polynomials on $\mathfrak{gl} (r,F)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386728/). These look like Tu's way of introducing invariance to an audience unfamiliar with group actions.

---

**Question**: For the paragraph before Example 23.1, what exactly does it mean that to say that $(23.1)$ "holds when $X$ is a matrix of indeterminates"?

**Context**: I'm asking this in relation to

1. the "i.e." part after.

   - 1.1. I think the "i.e." part is already from the assumption "$(23.1)$ holds for all $r \times r$ matrices $X$ of real numbers."
2. the use of Proposition B.1

   - 2.1. Perhaps this is supposed to be Proposition B.5 instead.
   - 2.2. Proposition B.1 is used twice more in [Section 23.1 (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHP6h.png). I'm actually wondering about the relevance of Proposition B.1 in all three uses, but I think I cannot ask about Proposition B.1 without first understanding "holds when $X$ is a matrix of indeterminates".

Comment: Just a quick note. I'd rather call it volume 2, his other book (Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology) is definitely more advanced.

Comment: @EternalBlood Had a feeling. Went to this book to learn about bundles because I didn't get bundles in Differential Forms. Thanks! However, from Volume 1: "This book has been conceived as the first volume of a tetralogy on geometry and topology. The second volume is Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology cited above. I hope that Volume 3, Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes, will soon see the light of day. Volume 4, Elements of Equivariant Cohomology, a long-running joint project with Raoul Bott before his passing away in 2005, is still under revision."